# Issue reguarding python objects and nested lists

Tags: python

Okay i will try to provide as much information as i can to make this easier for whoever has the time to give me some advice, hopefully one of you fine people will be able to help me.

I'm writing an arithmetic training sort of program. The idea of the program is that the user creates a 'session', they specify the math operation they want(/,*,-,+), the amount of equations, the range for the number generator(2 numbers, for example if they specify 1 and 5, all the numbers for the equations that get randomized will be in this range.).

Then the session is generated and the user completes the equations, at the end the user can check his answers and is presented with accuracy percentage, time taken to complete the session and the exact date and time the session was created.

The program is written in object orientated programming, with each session being an object. These objects are contained within a list which is pickled. The idea being that the user can go back over previous sessions and track their improvement or whatever.

The problem:
I'm having an impossible time iterating over each object and printing out all it's data.

The code for my program is as follows:

```
import pickle,time,random

class Session:
    def __init__(self,amount,operation,numgen_range):
        start_time = [int(time.strftime('%M', time.gmtime())),int(time.strftime('%S', time.gmtime()))]
        ID = main.get_id() + 1
        accuracy = 0
        rights = 0
        equations_data = []
        duration = [0,0]
        datetime = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime())
        self.session_data = [ID,amount,operation,numgen_range,datetime,accuracy,rights,equations_data,duration]
        main.save_id()

        if self.session_data[2] == '+':
            for i in range(self.session_data[1]):
                a = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                b = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                answer = a + b
                user_answer = int(input('{0} + {1} = '.format(a,b)))
                if answer == user_answer:
                    rightwrong = True
                    self.session_data[6] += 1
                else:
                    rightwrong = False
                eq_data = [a,self.session_data[2],b,answer,user_answer,rightwrong]
                self.session_data[7].append(eq_data)
        elif self.session_data[2] == '*':
            for i in range(self.session_data[1]):
                a = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                b = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                answer = a * b
                user_answer = int(input('{0} * {1} = '.format(a,b)))
                if answer == user_answer:
                    rightwrong = True
                    self.session_data[6] += 1
                else:
                    rightwrong = False
                eq_data = [a,self.session_data[2],b,answer,user_answer,rightwrong]
                self.session_data[7].append(eq_data)
        elif self.session_data[2] == '-':
            for i in range(self.session_data[1]):
                a = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                b = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                answer = a - b
                user_answer = int(input('{0} - {1} = '.format(a,b)))
                if answer == user_answer:
                    rightwrong = True
                    self.session_data[6] += 1
                else:
                    rightwrong = False
                eq_data = [a,self.session_data[2],b,answer,user_answer,rightwrong]
                self.session_data[7].append(eq_data)
        elif self.session_data[2] == '/':
            for i in range(self.session_data[1]):
                a = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                b = random.randint(self.session_data[3][0],self.session_data[3][1])
                answer = a / b
                user_answer = int(input('{0} / {1} = '.format(a,b)))
                if answer == user_answer:
                    rightwrong = True
                    self.session_data[6] += 1
                else:
                    rightwrong = False
                eq_data = [a,self.session_data[2],b,answer,user_answer,rightwrong]
                self.session_data[7].append(eq_data)

        end_time = [int(time.strftime('%M', time.gmtime())),int(time.strftime('%S', time.gmtime()))]
        if start_time[0] >= end_time[0]:
            self.session_data[8][0] = start_time[0] - end_time[0]
        else:
            self.session_data[8][0] = end_time[0] - start_time[0]
        if start_time[1] >= end_time[1]:
            self.session_data[8][1] = start_time[1] - end_time[1]
        else:
            self.session_data[8][1] = end_time[1] - start_time[1]

        self.session_data[5] = (self.session_data[6] / self.session_data[1]) * 100
        print('You got {0} problems correct out of {1}, your accuracy percentage was {2}%.\nYou took {3} minutes and {4} seconds to complete the session.'.format(self.session_data[6],self.session_data[1],int(self.session_data[5]),self.session_data[8][0],self.session_data[8][1]))

        while True:
            try:
                i = int(input('Enter 1 to check answers or 2 to return to the menu: '))
                if i == 1:
                    main.util = True
                    for i in self.session_data[7]:
                        if i[5]:
                            rw = 'CORRECT'
                        else:
                            rw = 'INCORRECT'
                        print('{0} {1} {2} = {3} Your Answer: {4} - {5}\n'.format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],rw))
                elif i == 2:
                    main.util = False
                    pass
                else:
                    raise ValueError
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(main.input_error_msg)
                continue

with open('data/saved_sessions.txt','rb') as file:
    saved_sessions = pickle.load(file)

class main:
    util = None
    input_error_msg = 'You entered an invalid input, try again.'

    def create():
        print('Create Session.')

        while True:
            try:
                amount = int(input('Enter the amount of equations you want: '))
                if amount < 1:
                    raise ValueError
                if amount > 50:
                    print('Sorry, the limit for equation amounts is 50, try again.')
                    continue
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(main.input_error_msg)
                continue

        while True:
            try:
                operation = input('Enter operation: ')
                if operation == '':
                    print('You must specify an operation for the session!')
                    continue
                if len(operation) != 1:
                    print(main.input_error_msg)
                    continue
                if "+" not in operation:
                    if "-" not in operation:
                        if "*" not in operation:
                            if "/" not in operation:
                                print("You failed to enter a valid equation type. Please try again.")
                                continue
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(main.input_error_msg)
                continue

        numgen_range = [0,0]
        while True:
            try:
                numgen_range[0] = int(input('Enter base range number: '))
                if numgen_range[0] < 0:
                    raise ValueError
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(main.input_error_msg)
                continue

        while True:
            try:
                numgen_range[1] = int(input('Enter ceiling range number: '))
                if numgen_range[1] < numgen_range[0]:
                    print('Sorry the ceiling range number cannot be larger than the base range number.')
                    continue
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(main.input_error_msg)
                continue

        while True:
            try:
                i = int(input('Enter 1 to generate this session or 2 to enter new specifications: '))
                if i == 1:
                    saved_sessions.append(Session(amount,operation,numgen_range))
                    main.pickle_sessions()
                    if main.util:
                        main.menu()
                    else:
                        main.menu(rmenu=True)
                elif i == 2:
                    main.create()
                else:
                    raise ValueError
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(main.input_error_msg)
                continue

    def get_id():
        try:
            with open('data/id_count.txt','rb') as file:
                count = pickle.load(file)
        except IOError:
            pass
        else:
            return count

    def save_id():
        try:
            with open('data/id_count.txt','wb') as file:
                pickle.dump(ID,file)
        except IOError:
            pass
        else:
            print('id count pickled.')

    def view_archive():
        print('View Session Archive')
        #view archive code to go here.    

    def menu(rmenu=False):
        if rmenu:
            while True:
                try:
                    i = int(input('Enter 1 to return to the menu: '))
                    if i == 1:
                        main.menu()
                    else:
                        raise ValueError
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print(main.input_error_msg)
                    continue
        else:
            print('Menu -[1]Create Session.[2]View Session Archive.[3]Exit.')
            while True:
                try:
                    i = int(input('Enter choice: '))
                    if i == 1:
                        main.create()
                    elif i == 2:
                        main.view_archive()
                    elif i == 3:
                        quit()
                    else:
                        raise ValueError
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print(main.input_error_msg)
                    continue

    def pickle_sessions():
        try:
            with open('data/saved_sessions.txt','wb') as file:
                pickle.dump(saved_sessions,file)
        except IOError:
            pass
        else:
            print('Sessions have been pickled.')

    def start():
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main.menu()

main.start()
```

Now what i want to do is, iterate over each object, go into it's session_data list, iterate over this and print out each bit of data, then iterate over the equations_data list which is element 7 in the session_data list, keeping in mind that equations_data is populated with yet more lists which contain each individual equation's data, so i want to iterate over that.

To sum it all up:
print out all the data from each object.

```
I thought something like:
for i in saved_sessions:
    for y in i.session_data:
        #print out elements then loop over equations_data on line below
        for x in i.session_data[7]:
            #print out elements
```

However this dosn't work, basically i cannot work out how to access the lists inside of the equations_data list, which is self.session_data[7], but when trying to iterate over this im returned with an index error.

Like i said what i want to do display each session one by one like:

```
ID: 1
Date: some date
Time: some time
Operation: +
Equations: 5
Right Answers: 5
Accuracy: 100%
Time Taken: 15 seconds

Equations:
1 + 5 = 6 Your Answer: 6
1 + 6 = 7 Your Answer: 7
1 + 7 = 8 Your Answer: 8
1 + 8 = 9 Your Answer: 9
1 + 9 = 10 Your Answer: 10
```

Any help regarding this problem would be hugely appreciated. Also i'm very keen on some brutally honest feedback on every aspect of my programming. Constructive criticism is encouraged.

Comment: Why do you believe that `7` is a valid index?

Comment: Did you even read the code man? Your 10 word reply isn't of much help.


If you read this part of the code:


     self.session_data =[ID,amount,operation,numgen_range,datetime,accuracy,rights,equations_data,duration]


and this part which is appending the eq_data lists to the equations_data list:

    self.session_data[7].append(eq_data)

This is why i believe 7 is a valid index, because the list i'm trying to access is the 7th element. This is confirmed by reading the code i posted in this post.


More importantly, why do you believe 7 ISNT a valid index?

Comment: Running this code gets a separate error: `TypeError: unbound method start() must be called with main instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`. You can't call unbound methods of a class this way.

Comment: This would work if you had `@staticmethod` before each method. (Alternatively, perhaps this works differently in the Python version you're using: I use 2.7)

Answer (score 3):

Why are you putting variables in a single list attribute? Why not make them all class attributes so you can access them by name not number? E.g., `self.equations_data`, `self.accuracy`, etc?

The problem with your nested loop is that it's too nested. You are iterating over `i.session_data[7]` n-times, where n is evidently 9, the length of session_data. You'd want something like:

```
for i in saved_sessions:
    for j in range(len(i.session_data)):
        if j!=7:
            y=i.session_data[j]
            # print out your elements here
    for x in i.session_data[7]:
        #print out elements
```

**BUT DON'T DO THAT.** Revise your approach so that you're not saving attributes in that one list. At least store them in a dictionary so you can access them by name. Better yet, store them as attributes of the class.

As for printing out your class, you should implement the `__str__(self)` method in `Session` to put the data in the class instance into a string per your desired format, e.g.:

```
class Session(object):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        out = 'ID:%s\nAMOUNT:%d ... '%(self.ID, self.amount, ...)   # And so on.
        return out
```

That way you can just execute:

```
for session in saved_sessions:
    print str(session)
```

And that's it. How pretty! (And FYI, it's more Pythonic to use descriptive words for your variable names when looping with `for ... in`.)

**Other recommendations**

1. As @David Robinson points out, your class `Main` won't run as you want it to. You should [read about Python classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) before continuing, since you're making some assumptions about them that aren't correct. You must declare methods static with `@staticmethod` if you want to access them without an instance, and I don't think this is very Pythonic.

2&3. Use `re` instead of nested `if` statements, e.g.:

```
if not re.search(r'[\*\-\+\/]', operation):
    # Invalid operation, you should raise an exception here
    raise ValueError
```

4 . Review [the style guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and format your code appropriately. It will help you start writing more Pythonically, which will make your code clearer and better.

Those were things that caught my eye

Comment: +1 for storing session data in named attributes in an object, and for writing a \_\_str\_\_ method!

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

So very grateful for the insight. For some stupid reason i thought putting all my object attributes in a list was somehow making life easier but now i see how stupid that is. And i cant believe i didn't think about the __str__ method, very stupid of me.

Anyways i've taken all advice on board here. 

Very appreciative your advice means alot everyone, thank you.